# Cassandra / Scylla / NodeJS - Validation failed for type org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type: got 8 bytes

Tags: node.js, cassandra, scylla

I have this function:

```
async function insertGameSession(user_id, start_date, gameId) {
    const session_id = scyllaDB.types.TimeUuid.now(); // Generate a new time-based UUID

    const query = `
        INSERT INTO game_sessions (session_id, user_id, game_id, start_date, end_date)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?,?, null);
    `;

    // Execute the query with parameters using the client from index.js
    await dbcllient.execute(query, [session_id, int(user_id), gameId, start_date]);

    return session_id;
}
```

I am sure `user_id` is number type and it is passed correctly to the function `insertGameSession` . When trying to execute the query I get this error:

```
Error inserting game session: ResponseError: Exception while binding column user_id: marshaling error: Validation failed for type org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type: got 8 bytes
```

This is the schema of my SvyllaDB table:

```
create table game_sessions
(
    session_id timeuuid,
    user_id    int,
    end_date   timestamp,
    game_id    int,
    start_date timestamp,
    primary key ((session_id, user_id))
)
    with caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL'}
     and compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
     and compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
     and dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0
     and speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it ?

Comment: It looks like a bug in the driver which passes an integer as a 64-bit number instead of 32-bit number as CQL expect (because "int" in CQL is a signed 32-bit integer). I don't know how the nodejs driver can have such a basic bug, though... Do you get the same error message for both Cassandra and Scylla?